# class file for redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, jedis

I have my RedisConfig class as:

```
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

When I try to build it I am facing the following issue:

```
ava: cannot access redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig
  class file for redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig not found
```

Now, what I tried is I removed the `redisStandaloneConfiguration` from `JedisConnectionFactory` and just returned new `new JedisConnectionFactory()`.
Although, I am not getting the above error, I am facing a new one:

```
Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/iplbetting/iplbettingtracker/config/RedisConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception with message: redis/clients/jedis/JedisClientConfig
```

When I inspect further, it's caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: redis.clients.jedis.JedisClientConfig`

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`, although I tried adding the jedis library with version 3.x, I was still facing the same issue.

Here are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
```

Is there any configuration i am missing?